# Google OAuth2 for Android using python-social-auth

Tags: android, django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I have a Django project, that implements Google OAuth2 with *python-social-auth* package. It works fine for Web applications. My config in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.getenv('GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.getenv('GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'entity.oauth.backends.CustomGoogleOAuth2',
    'entity.oauth.backends.CustomFacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'entity.oauth.strategies.CustomStrategy'
```

After completing the request I generate JWT tokens for the user:

```
def jwt_do_complete(backend, login, user=None, redirect_name='next',
                    *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    if user:
        if user_is_active(user):
            # Get the JWT payload for the user.
            refresh = TokenObtainPairSerializer.get_token(user)
            payload = {
                'refresh': str(refresh),
                'access': str(refresh.access_token)
            }
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Unauthorized', 'The user account is disabled.', status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Unauthorized', 'The user account does not exist.', status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    return user, payload
```

So the workflow of the authorization is the following:

1. Frontend authenticates by Google form and receives code and other information.
2. It sends it to the complete route of the Django server.
3. Django verify the code with help of *python-social-auth*.
4. Django sends back JWT tokens.

Here is the complete view:

```
@never_cache
@csrf_exempt
@psa(f'{NAMESPACE}:complete')
def complete_with_jwt(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
    """Authentication complete view"""
    try:
        user, token_info = jwt_do_complete(
            request.backend,
            _do_login,
            user=request.user,
            redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, request=request,
            *args, **kwargs
        )
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if len(e.args) != 3:
            raise
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            'status': e.args[0],
            'message': e.args[1],
        }), status=e.args[2])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(token_info))
```

It works fine as I said earlier. But when it comes to Android apps, there is a problem: Google credentials for Android do not have client_secret, just client_id.

[image: Google credentials]

But still Google documentations about OAuth in Android involve client_secret without explaining how to get one. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code

[image: Google Android OAuth2 docs]

So to put this together: **How to obtain client_secret for Google Android OAuth2? Is there a different approach for Android apps to perform authentication?**

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate